# How do I have C recognise libaries that haven't been installed properly?

Tags: c, gcc, relative-path, gmp

For a C project I'm writing I need to use the GMP library, which I have untarred into my Home directory (using OpenBSD OS with bash). I'm working with others over git, so I can't change the headers to relative files and at the moment the GCC is giving errors about not being able to find it. I don't have root privelidges, so I can't just install it.

How do I get the GCC to look for the GMP library in my home folder instead of the usual place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiling use the argument `-I` to tell GCC where to look for header files, and `-L` to tell GCC where to look for libraires.

For example:

```
$ gcc -I/location/of/library/headers -c foo.c -o foo.o
$ gcc -L/location/of/library/libs foo.o -o foo -llibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use a environment variable you set to point to the location where the GMP library is installed.

For example this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export GMP_PATH=/home/mylibs/gmp
```

and in your makefile (or script) you can use something like:

```
gcc my_file1.c my_file2.c my_file3.c -I${GMP_PATH}/include
```

I don't know the directory structure of GMP library but you should be able to obtain the include path based on GMP_PATH variable, which is pointing to the GMP directory.

So it is possible to have something like `${GMP_PATH}/include`, `${GMP_PATH}/src/include` etc.